# Unable to access MongoDB server running on AWS EC2 machine

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, nodes, mongojs

I am running MongoDB server v6.0.4 on AWS EC2 Linux machine, which is publicly accessible.

*Using MongoDB:     6.0.4
Using Mongosh:      1.8.0*

/etc/mongod.conf

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  ipv6: true
  bindIp: ::,0.0.0.0  # Tried with public DNS and IP as well here.


security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /etc/mongodkeyfile.key

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rs0
```

Able to perform all DB operations by connecting through mongosh on the same machine,

EC2 machine is responding when I ping from my Mac machine.

[image: Here is the ping result]

**Whereas when I try connecting through Nodejs application, getting below error**

```
MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip-xx-x-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal
at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/durgalovababupadala/myprojects/continuum-electrolite/ev-server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:293:38)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

And here is my sample code,

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Replace the uri string with your connection string.
const uri = "mongodb://<user>:<pwd>@<EC2-PublicIP>:27017/<dbname>?replicaSet=rs0&useUnifiedTopology=true";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    const database = client.db('test');
    console.log(database);
    const myColl = database.collection("pizzas");
    const doc = { name: "Neapolitan pizza", shape: "round" };
    const result = await myColl.insertOne(doc);
    console.log(
      `A document was inserted with the _id: ${result.insertedId}`,
    );

  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Thanks in advance,

**Update:** Executed simple node application with MongoDB connection on Same EC2 machine, and it works.

Comment: What are the incoming rules specified in the security group for this EC2 instance?

Comment: I guess you miss the TLS/SSL certificate, see [TLS/SSL Configuration for Clients](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/)

Comment: @ArpitJain SG has inbound rule to allow all IPV4 IPV6 traffic from all IPs through all ports. Thanks.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is SSL configuration mandatory? I didn't set up any SSL config.

Comment: Oh, I mixed it with Atlas. I guess you have to set `net.ipv6: true`. Setting just `net.bindIp: "::"` does not enable IPv6. And you may put all hosts of your replicat set in connection string.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I will give a try with net.ipv6: true,  fyi: even I tried configuring net.bindIp: public-dns-name, still no luck same error. And I have single instance in my cluster. Thanks

Comment: [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.bindIpAll) is quite clear: "*mongos or mongod only supports IPv6 if started with net.ipv6 : true. Specifying net.bindIpAll alone does not enable IPv6 support.*"

Comment: ```# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  ipv6: true
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,ec2-xx-0-xxx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com```.   Tried with this config, still facing same issue. Thanks,

Comment: Did you try `bindIpAll: true`? Should be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip-xx-x-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal`.  Note the *.internal* at the end.  If you are not inside the EC2 network, that won't resolve.

When connecting to a replica set, the hostnames and IP addresses in the connection string are the seed list. The driver will attempt to connect to each host in the seed list in turn, and once it gets a connection will run isMaster.

The isMaster command will return the list of member hostname:port in the replica set, as entered in the configuration document. The client then drops the original connection, and connects to the discovered nodes.

In your case, the following happens:

- The client successfully connects to <EC2-PublicIP>:27017 and runs isMaster
- The isMaster command returns a list of nodes, including ip-xx-x-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal
- The client drops the initial connection and attempts to connect to ip-xx-x-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal:27017
- The DNS server fails to resolve the internal name

To fix this, rebuild or reconfigure the replica set, ensuring that the valued set for the `host` field in each member is a hostname that can be resolve both inside and outside the EC2 network.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joe you saved me, rs.status() shows ecc2 internal ip in members list, I just updated members with public it started working..